# Recurring Payments

Tags: web, paypal

I am implementing paypal website standard method. using this method i want to implement installments. Installments means that the buyer will have to pay the money. He cannot cancel this subscription unless he has paid all the installments. Can any buddy help?

regards
Qasim Ali

Answer (score 1):

The PayPal [API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_CreateRecurringPayments) has good documentation on this.

I don't know what kind of support PayPal has for 'enforcing' contracts.  In my experience the customer has ALL the power here.

They can simply dispute a charge and he can get refunded, and you have to pay.  The best bet is to make your product/service so satisfactory that the customer will think they are robbing you ;)